# Inserting multiple entries in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to create barcodes that increment by 1 for an entered quantity and add each of them to a MongoDB collection.

I use `db.controlNumber.insert({controlNumber})` to do this, and I also use
`console.log(controlNumber)` to see my result. However, in the database, the incremented number will go to the max and enter that many times, where the console.log shows it increment.

```
while (i < count) {
  i++;

  controlNumber.controlNumber = controlVar[0] + "-" + controlVar[1] + "-" + 
  controlVar[2] + "-" + controlVar[3] + "-000" + i;
  db.controlNumber.insert(controlNumber);
  console.log(controlNumber);     
}
```

I expect my mongoDB collection to have control number (for example if user wants 5 control numbers)

```
a-b-c-d-001  
a-b-c-d-002  
...  
a-b-c-d-005
```

Instead, it makes 5 entries of

```
a-b-c-d-005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mutating `controlNumber.controlNumber`. Instead, create a new object to insert:

```
const toInsert = Object.assign({}, controlNumber, { controlNumber: i });
db.controlNumber.insert(toInsert)
```

It'd likely also be worth either using `async/await` or promises to handle asynchronous calls. If you do `await db.controlNumber.insert(controlNumber)` you wouldn't have run into any problems because it would have waited for the document to be fully inserted before moving on to the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the await db.controlNumber.insert(controlNumber) and I received the error:

await db.controlNumber.insert(controlNumber);
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes, that error is telling you that you can only use `await` when you're within an async function. It's worth taking a look at the docs -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function